# Dialogflow can't create more agent due to gcp quota

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dialogflow-es

i am trying to create another agent in my dialogflow account but i can't because my gcp project limit is reached so i deleted the other useless agent but still the same issue now i tried deleting some project from gcp but still same error persist. how can i increase the quota of my dialogflow agent ?

[image]

Thank you 
regards saif

Answer (score 3):

Google Cloud Projects that are deleted take 30 days to completely delete. In the meantime, they are counted against your quota.

The limit is in place to make sure people don't abuse the resource or that a wayward process doesn't suddenly create tons of projects. They are reasonable about allocating more.

As the orange box indicates, you can request more projects through that link, which probably goes to https://support.google.com/code/contact/project_quota_increase. In it, be reasonable in your request, and mention that you're experimenting, that this is why you've used up all the projects initially allocated, and that you've already deleted some, but need more to continue your work in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

While use of the Dialogflow Standard Edition is free, there are limits on the amount of requests that you can make. You must bay Google Cloud Platform resources.